# Monacaでビルドするとnend広告が表示されない

Tags: monaca, nend

Monacaデバッガでは、[公式のドキュメント](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/tips/external_services/nend_ad/)を参考に広告を表示することができますが、実機にビルドすると全く広告が表示されません。
Cordovaのバージョンは5.2.0です。
同現象に遭遇した方もしくは、ノウハウをお持ちの方がいましたらアドバイスをいただきたいです。。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

`config.xml`に下記のコードを追加してみてください。

```
<preference name="monaca:DisableCookie" value="false"/>
```

12/17追記

実際に動いているコードは下記のとおりです。
Cordova 5.2にアップデート後、広告が表示されなくなり、旧バージョンとの差分を調査し、`config.xml`に上記のコードを追加したところ動作しました。

HTML

```
<div id="nend_wrapper"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var nend_params = {"media":xx,"site":xxxxx,"spot":xxxxxx,"type":x,"oriented":x};

addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var nendAdSpace = document.querySelector("div[id^=nend_adspace]");
        var nendAdAnchors = nendAdSpace.querySelectorAll("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < nendAdAnchors.length; i++) {
            (function() {
                var hrefShelter = nendAdAnchors[i].href;
                nendAdAnchors[i].removeAttribute("href");
                nendAdAnchors[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    window.open(hrefShelter, "_system", "location=no");
                }, false);
            })();
        }
    }, 3000);
}, false);
```

12/17再追記

上記例では`InAppBrowser`プラグインが必要となります。
いただいたコメント内容からおそらくこれっぽい症状ですね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
しかし、ダメそうです・・・別方法をさがしてみます！
今回は以下のブログを参考にしました
http://d-yummy.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/10/19/212843?_ga=1.80160287.922256416.1396272023

Comment: http://keimapj.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/12/14/onsenUI%E3%81%A7nend%E5%BA%83%E5%91%8A%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA
の方法をすこし変えればやりたいことができそうです！

Comment: こちらInappBrowserはいれていたのですが、バージョンが最新になっておらずビルドしていました。。
バージョンを最新にしたら無事表示されました！！