# Monaca で nend（ネンド広告）が表示しない

Tags: monaca, nend

Monaca の公式ドキュメントを読みながら nend（ネンド広告）の表示を試みています。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/tips/external_services/nend_ad/

ですが、上手く表示できません。

自分としては公式ドキュメントのとおりに行っているつもりなのですが、どこがボトルネックになっていて、何が原因なのかがまったく分からず詰まってしまいました。

【やりたいこと】
　プロジェクト「最小限のテンプレート」の素の状態に、広告（nend）を表示させる

- 使っているテンプレートは「最小限のテンプレート」
- Angular や Onsen UI は使用していない
- Cordova のバージョンは 5.2.0
- 検証端末は Android 5.0、Monacaデバッカーのバージョンは5.0.2
- Monacaデバッカー上では広告が表示されず。デバックビルドを実機にインストールしても広告は表示されない

漠然としており雲をつかむような質問で申し訳ありません。
「ここを気をつけた方がいいよ」みたいなアドバイスでも結構です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

追伸：
公式ドキュメントの手順が「2013年5月現在」とだいぶ古いように感じるのですが、公式側でアップデートする予定はないのでしょうか？

Comment: stackoverflowに似たような質問がありますので、そこに掲載されたコードを試してみてください。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20040/monaca%E3%81%A7%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8nend%E5%BA%83%E5%91%8A%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/

Comment: 紹介していただいたリンク先のコードを使用することでうまく動作しました。
ありがとうございました。

※「公式ドキュメントの情報が古かった」というのが原因なのでしょう。
　公式側にはドキュメントの速やかな更新を期待したいです。

Comment: 下記リンク先に同様の質問があり、それを参照して本件は解決しました。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20040/monaca%E3%81%A7%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8nend%E5%BA%83%E5%91%8A%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/

Comment: 私はこちらに掲載されたコードを参考にしました。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5969/monaca%E3%81%A7nend%E5%BA%83%E5%91%8A%E3%82%92%E5%88%A5%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%A6%E3%81%A7%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/ ただし、リンク先が複数ある場合、すべてのリンク先が最後のリンク先に書き換えられてしまうため、最初にコメントしたコードとなりました。コピー＆ペーストでも問題ありませんが、どのように動いているか確認して自分なりにカスタマイズするのがベストだと思います。

Comment: 公式がここを見ているかどうかはわかりませんから、ドキュメントの更新については公式の問い合わせ窓口を利用したほうがよいと思います。ドキュメントの右下にFeedbackというリンクがありますし。

Comment: （既存のQ&Aそのままで解決したとのことなので、重複としてクローズしました）